# Reading text file into an array in C

Tags: c, file, loops, for-loop, fgets

I want to parse a .txt file into a 1D array in C. I'm using the fgets function to read the contents of the file into the array("waveform" as the array into which the file contents are to be stored - defined as a "char"). The saved values need to be saved into a new array as integer values. I am not sure where I am going wrong. 
P.S: I am new to programming in C, please bear with me :)
Please ignore the indexing issues, done due to pasting

```
int main(){
    int a, win[10];

    FILE *filename = fopen("testFile.txt","r");
    char waveform[10];

    if (filename == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening file.\n");
        exit(8);
    }

    for(int i =0;1;i++){
        if(fgets(waveform[i], 10, filename) == NULL);
        break;

                if(i < 10)
            {
           a = atoi(waveform[i]);
           win[i] = a;
            }
         }

    fclose(filename);

    return 0; 
}
```

[Compiler errors - image embedded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dp5O.png)

Data in testFile.txt:
1 to 10 in a row vector.

Comment: You have a trailing `;` on the `if(fgets...` line that shouldn't be there.

Comment: `atoi` needs a **string**. Where are all the compiler errors?

Comment: Please do [edit] the question

Comment: I have embedded the compiler errors image

Comment: Please copy the compiler errors. Only use images when necessary.

Comment: You need to show a minimal example of `testFile.txt`.

Comment: Avoid posting images of text in the future. Plain text is always the easiest to read and the most versatile format!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track. Here is my contribution on the topic:

1. Open the file (`fopen`)
2. Count number of lines (`getc` and `rewind`)
3. Read all lines into array (`getline`)
4. Free memory and close file (`free` and `fclose`)

Code example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

  // Open File
  const char fname[] = "testFile.txt";

  FILE *fp = fopen(fname, "r");

  if( !fp )
    goto error_open_file;
  printf("Opened file: %s\n", fname); 

  // Count Lines
  char cr;
  size_t lines = 0;

  while( cr != EOF ) {
    if ( cr == '\n' ) {
      lines++;
    }
    cr = getc(fp);
  }
  printf("Number of lines: %ld\n", lines); 
  rewind(fp);

  // Read data
  {// 'goto' + data[lines] causes error, introduce block as a workaround
    char *data[lines];
    size_t n;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
      data[i] = NULL;
      size_t n = 0;

      getline(&data[i], &n, fp);

      if ( ferror( fp ) )
        goto error_read_file;

    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
      printf("%s", data[i]);
      free(data[i]);
    }
  }

  // Close File
  fclose(fp);

  return 0;

error_read_file:
  perror("fopen ");
  return 1;

error_open_file:
  perror("getline ");
  return 2;

}
```

Comment: You are very welcome. Make note of the call to `free` as per instruction in the `getline` manpage (execute `man getline` in the terminal), it is often forgotten.

Answer (score 1):

There are several errors in this loop

```
for(int i =0;1;i++){
    if(fgets(waveform[i], 10, filename) == NULL);
    break;

            if(i < 10)
        {
       a = atoi(waveform[i]);
       win[i] = a;
        }
     }
```

For starters there is a semicolon after the if statement

```
    if(fgets(waveform[i], 10, filename) == NULL);
                                               ^^^
```

Secondly the fgets call

```
fgets(waveform[i], 10, filename) 
              ^^^
```

is invalid because the type of the expression `waveform[i]` is `char`.
And correspondingly this statement

```
a = atoi(waveform[i]);
```

is also invalid.

There must be at least

```
fgets( waveform, 10, filename)
```

and

```
a = atoi( waveform );
```

I suppose that each line of the file contains exactly one number. (Otherwise you should use for example `sscanf` to extract numbers from a line using an internal additional loop.)

The loop can look like

```
int i = 0;
for ( ; i < 10 && fgets( waveform, 10, filename) != NULL; i++ )
{
    a = atoi( waveform );
    win[i] = a;
}
```

After the loop the variable `i` will contain the actual number of elements of the array `win`.

Pay attention to that the name `filename` is not good for a pointer of the type `FILE *`. File name is the string `"testFile.txt"` in your code.

Comment: Massive thanks for helping me clear a lot of things :).

I am not sure on what you mean by "Pay attention to that the name filename is not good for a pointer of the type FILE *. File name is the string "testFile.txt" in your code." You mean to say that "filename" is not a good pointer name?

Comment: @samz12 It is just not very suitable name of the variable.:)

Comment: Ok got it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the `fgets()` function you don't have to put it into a loop. Indeed, the second argument of `fgets()` is the number of elements you want to read.
I would have put the `fgets()` into a singl-line instruction, and then loop from 0 to 10 to make the conversion from char to int with the `atoi()` function. 
Moreover, you have a `;` at the end of your `if()` statement, so you'll execute it not in the way you want.

Comment: But I'm not sure if using a single line fgets() will read every row of the text file. After using a single line fgets(), if I prnt the output I get only the 1st element.

Comment: According to the manual page : "fgets()  reads  in  at most one less than size characters from stream and stores
       them into the buffer pointed to by s.  Reading stops after an EOF or a  newline.
       If  a  newline  is  read, it is stored into the buffer.  A terminating null byte
       ('\0') is stored after the last character in the buffer."